# Removing duplicate files upload-files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, lodash

I use lodash clonedeep for uploading files.

I wrote a function that forbids uploading identical files. But if I delete some file after uploading, it still stays in state and I can't upload file with the same name.

What can I do to get the file removed from the state too?

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

//state to store uploaded file's name
const [fileNames, setFileNames] = useState([]);

const onSelectFile = (e) => {
    try {
        let fileArr = cloneDeep(files);
        let promises = [];
        for (let file of e.target.files) {
            promises.push(
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const fileName = file.name
                    //if the file has not been already uploaded
                    if (!fileNames.includes(fileName)) {
                        //add the current fileName in state
                        setFileNames([fileName, ...fileNames]);
                        const type = file.type;
                        let reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                        reader.onload = function (evt) {
                            const fileData = evt.target.result;
    
                            fileArr.push({
                                name: fileName,
                                type: type,
                                data: fileData,
                                comment: "",
                                id: `${new Date().getTime()}_${fileName}`,
                                canDelete: true
                            });
    
                            if (typeof props.onFileSelected == "function")
                                props.onFileSelected(fileArr);
    
                            resolve(true);
                        }
                        reader.onerror = function (evt) {
                            console.log("error reading file");
                            reject(false);
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("File has already been uploaded");
                        reject(false);
                    }
                })
            );
        }

        Promise.all(promises).then(r => {
            setFiles(fileArr);
        })
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

I don’t know what to do, it took me 40 hours to think, but I still didn’t understand anything.

Comment: You're deleting the file, but not telling the state that the file has been deleted. Can you include your logic for how you are deleting the file, just realized you aren't actually storing the file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from your question, you aren't saving the images on disk. You also haven't included the logic you are using for deleting files. Either way, the implementation is similar.

So when a user deletes a file, assuming they are deleting by filename, we use the `filter()` method to only keep those that aren't the file we want to delete.

```
const fileNameToRemove = 'example.txt';

setFiles(files.filter(file=> file.name !== fileNameToRemove));
setFileNames(fileNames.filter(name => name !== fileNameToRemove));
```

So you will want to do something like this, I haven't used clonedeep like you're in this example, but it's a quick add. I have also moved the read file section into its own function, and am I returning a promise, so I can use async/await within the core upload function.

```
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  const [fileNames, setFileNames] = useState([]);

  const readFileAsync = async (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

      fileReader.onload = () => {
        resolve(fileReader.result);
      }

      fileReader.onerror = () => {
        reject(null);
      }
    })
  }

  const onSelectFile = async (e) => {
    const uploadingFiles = e.target.files;

    for (const file of uploadingFiles) {
      const fileName = file.name;

      if (fileNames.includes(fileName)) {
        console.error("File duplicate");

        continue;
      }

      try {
        const fileContentsBuffer = await readFileAsync(file);

        setFiles([...files, {
          name: fileName,
          type: file.type,
          data: fileContentsBuffer,
          comment: "",
          id: `${new Date().getTime()}_${fileName}`,
          canDelete: true
        }])

        setFileNames([...fileNames, fileName]);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error reading file");

        continue;
      }
    }

  }

  const deleteFile = (fileName) => {
    const fileDataToDelete = files.find((file) => {
      return file.name === fileName;
    })

    if (!fileDataToDelete.canDelete) {
      console.error('Can\'t delete file!');
      return;
    }

    setFileNames(fileNames.filter(name => name != fileName));
    setFiles(files.filter(file => file.name != fileName && file.canDelete));
  }
```